# Redundant code for objects name-values in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object, javascript-objects, jsobject

I defined a **js object** whose name-value pairs are function expressions with more or less same function definition. The key names of the object match the functions of the module imported from outside.

```
const myModule = require('some_module');    //some module imported from outside

const myObj = {};

myObj.abc = (param1, param2, param3) => {
  myModule.abc(param1, param2, param3);
  // some algorithm (say algo)
}

myObj.xyz= (param1, param2, param3) => {
  myModule.xyz(param1, param2, param3);
  // same algorithm (algo)
}

myObj.pqr= (param1, param2, param3) => {
  myModule.pqr(param1, param2, param3);
  // same algorithm (algo)
}

//All the three names (abc, xyz, pqr) have nearly same function definitions.
```

My question is; is there any better way to reduce the lines of code because the code seems redundant?

Comment: Could you share how you call them?

Comment: Just be wary of sacrificing readability for a few lines of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd iterate over an array of method names instead to define the functions:

```
const methods = ['abc', 'xyz', 'pqr'];
for (const key of methods) {
  myObj[key] = (param1, param2, param3) => {
    myModule[key](param1, param2, param3);
    // some algorithm (say algo)
  };
}
```

Comment: Actually, those function names (func1, func2, func3) are generic in reality, Here I used these names for demonstration purpose only. E.g func1 is abc, func2 is xyz, func3 is pqr.

Comment: As always, please include the *actual* code in your question to receive useful answers

Comment: Okay, I made the edits. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Simple tweak, just make an array of method names